# Can I control an extractor fan with a ceiling fan controller?

Tags: fan, motor-controller

I've designed and built a flush ceiling kitchen extractor fan.

I'm planning to use a [Vent Axia ACM150 (50 Watt) inline fan](https://www.vent-axia.com/range/acm100-200-acm250-315)

I'm trying to avoid having switches and knobs everwhere.

The idea (if any good) is to use a [Westinghouse Ceiling Fan remote control](http://www.westinghouselighting.eu/lighting-accessories/ceiling-fan-accessories/controls/radio-frequency-ceiling-fan-and-light-remote-control-7226640.aspx) The spec says "Maximum Fan Amps 100" (I think they mean 100 watts).

Will this idea work, or will I burn something out?

Answer (score 1):

The Westinghouse remote control is specifically designed for Westinghouse ceiling fans. The Vent-Axia fan manufacturer offers a speed control unit that is specifically designed for the Vent-Axia fan. The controller for one may or may not work for the other. The Westinghouse control might work, might work but not control the speed very well, or might not work at all. If something is going to be damaged, it is more likely to be the control unit, but the fan could be damaged if the control unit causes it to stall and it is not turned off right away. If you could find a remote control unit that just turned the fan on and off, that would be a safer thing to use. A remote control that contained a simple switch for high, medium. low and off might also work.

Comment: Cheers, Its not looking to good :( I was aim for clean lines in my kitchen, minimal switches,minimal budget.

Answer (score 0):

Size 150, is with shaded pole motors, capacitor start and run motors.

Most SS speed controllers are **Not to be used with Capacitor Start or Capacitor Run Motors.**

Although yours is rated for 100A , you can expect this much current with a cap start with triac control.

Consult factory for advice.

Comment: Many thanks, somehow I don think either the fan or controller manufacturer will want to commit to someone else product :(

Comment: Then ask if you can use your existing 100A light dimmer, and see what they say...as I said it may work with a reactor in series